# How to deploy files using Group Policy

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, file-sharing, windows-server-2003-r2

I wish to share a couple files to every computer on my domain. I know I need to use Group Policy, but I'm not really sure where to go from there. I am using Windows Server 2003 R2.

Comment: Is this a corporate domain?

Comment: Yes, it is a corporate domain.

Comment: Corporate domain and IT issues are off-topic here. I have marked this to be migrated to [sf].

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what are your specific goal, however, you can create a group policy for "`Computer Configuration`" as shown in the screenshot. There are multiple options i.e. `Create` and `Update`, `overwrite` etc. You can place the Source file in `SYSVOL` so all domain members will have access to it, centrally.

[image: Preferences for Files]

Comment: What do you specify for the **Source file(s)**? What do you specify for the **Destination File**? What do you specify for the **Destination File** for the file to go into a user's **Desktop** folder?

Comment: source will be the source file you want to copy to the Remote machines and Destination will be the Destination including file name/extension i.e. `c:\testdir\test.text`

Comment: How do you specify the user's desktop (e.g. E:\Profiles\Users\Ian\Desktop, C:\Users\Ian\Desktop, C:\Documents & Settings\Ian\My Desktop\)?

Comment: you can use something like this i guess `%userprofile%\Desktop`. There are plenty of environment variables to move around based on user profiles, google will be your best friend. Good luck. Something like this may work `%systemdrive%\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

You could use group policy preferences to copy files down .

There's a tutorial of that on the internet at http://kunaludapi.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/copy-files-on-all-computers-using-group.html

I've used this to copy down some files in the past - only thing I think you would find is that you would need to use a new OS to setup the policy e.g. GPMC on windows 7.

There's a supportability table at http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/12/group-policy-preferences-prerequisites/

Comment: Microsoft reference at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772536(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Server 2003 doesn't have support for Group Policy Preferences

Comment: I thought you could install them - https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6955 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943729

Answer (score 0):

On a 2003 domain it's probably easiest to do this with a batch file e.g.

```
IF NOT EXIST c:\local\path\to\file.txt  
xcopy \\source\file.txt c:\local\path\to\file.txt
```

You can run this as a logon script or startup script using group policy.